# How to display a 'delete button' on the touchbar?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, touch-bar

I recently got a new MacbookPro with the Touch Bar, I would like to add a button to the control strip that acts like a typical delete key, AKA it removes the character *in front* of the cursor.

Is it possible to add a delete button without paid software?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you already can do that without the touchbar :

- With the regular Delete key can be done by holding down the Function, or fn key while pressing it.
- By pressing Control + D.
- You can delete the entire word behind the cursor by pressing Control + Delete or Option + Delete.
- You can delete the entire line of text or paragraph behind the cursor by pressing Command + Delete.

But if you really want a one-press-button solution, you could use  [BetterTouchTool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/) (and for $5, is almost a *free* option...) that allow you to make personalize shortcut ; or simply do an automator workflow to do a delete action (every workflow you make will appear on a section in the touchbar, more info [here](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3299299/mojave-how-to-make-automator-shortcuts-for-mbp-touch-bar.html)).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this but in theory I think it could work.

You can try making the touchbar show function keys for that app so that you do not need to hold fn: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207240

Then download Karabiner-Elements (which is free) to change one of the function keys to a delete key.